# Error en máximos y mínimos negativos Python

Tags: python

estoy realizando un curso de python y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

he de determinar el número menor de una lista, mientras los valores son positivos perfecto, pero al introducir negativos, no comprendo que valores está cogiendo:

```
lista = ['-1', '-100', '-2', '-1000', '-50']
menor = 'init' 

for x in lista:
    if menor == 'init':
        menor = x
    else:
        menor = x if x < menor else menor
print('menor', menor)
print(max(lista))
print(min(lista))
```

Salida:

```
menor -1
-50
-1
```

Seguro que es una obviedad pero no lo consigo, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Estas comparando **cadenas**, no valores. Las cadenas se comparan alfabéticamente. Debes usar `lista = [-1, -100, -2, -1000, -50]`.

Comment: @CandidMoe Muchas gracias!

Comment: pequeña optimización. Si haces `menor=lista[0]` en vez de "init", no necesitas comparar con "init" después

Comment: @abulafia y hacer `for x in lista[1:]` para evitar comparar nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Como tu pregunta es **"determinar el número menor de una lista"** lo primero es que la lista debe ser una lista de numeros, no de strings.

```
lista =[-1, -100, -2, -1000, -50]
```

Para calcular el mínimo y máximo tienes varias opciones:

- 1. Tu propia función:

```
minimo = maximo = lista[0]
```

El primer valor de la lista es el máximo y el mínimo, luego recorres la lista.

```
for x in lista[1:]:
    if x < minimo: minimo = x
    if x > maximo: maximo = x

print(f'Mi mínimo= {minimo}')
print(f'Mi máximo= {maximo}')
```

**Obtenemos:**

```
Mi mínimo= -1000
Mi máximo= -1
```

- 2. Ordenar la lista:
     Una vez ordenada la lista el primer valor es el mínimo y el último el máximo.

```
lista_ordenada = sorted(lista)
print(f'Mi mínimo ordenado = {lista_ordenada[0]}')
print(f'Mi máximo ordenado = {lista_ordenada[-1]}')
```

**Obtenemos:**

```
Mi mínimo ordenado = -1000
Mi máximo ordenado = -1
```

- 3. La función de python:

```
print(f'El mínimo es {min(lista)}')
print(f'El máximo es {max(lista)}')
```

**Obtenemos:**

```
El mínimo es -1000
El máximo es -1
```